# Vertx HTTPClient with CompletableFuture block the callback Thread

Tags: java, java-8, httpclient, vert.x, completable-future

I am facing a very weird problem.

I am working on Vert.x and from handler I am calling REST APIs using `HttpClientRequest` of Vert.x. Now I am having a `CompletableFuture` which I am completing in the response handler of the `HttpClientRequest`. Later, I am using `CompletableFuture.get()`. But whenever `get()` method is called, the main thread is blocked (as expected), but it remains blocked forever. I am not seeing the callback happen on my response Handler and it is stuck for forever.

Here is code:

```
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpClientRequest;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod;
import io.vertx.core.json.Json;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpClient;

CompletableFuture<JsonObject> comp = new CompletableFuture<JsonObject>();   
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(); //This object initialized and set the endpoit, port and domain name.
HttpClientRequest request = httpClient.request(HttpMethod.POST, requestURI, response -> {
        response.bodyHandler(body -> {
            //do some process
            comp.complete(new JsonObject(body);
        });
    }).exceptionHandler(e -> {
        //log the error
        comp.completeExceptionally(e);
    });

request.end();
//after some process
comp.get();  // here main thread is stuck forever.
```

My API gives 200 response, I saw in it Wireshark and also If I do `comp.thenAccept()` the callback is executed and it gives my result.

Why is this happening and what is the solution?

Note: I know that it is not recommendation to use `Completable.get()` method but in my use-case, I have to use it.

Here is sample code which is giving me issue:

```
package io.vertx.starter;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.http.*;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class SampleVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  public void start ( Future startFuture ) throws Exception {
    Future<Void> future = Future.future ();
    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer ();

    Router router = Router.router (vertx);
    router.get ("/sample").handler (this::sampeHandler);
    router.get ("/testcompletableblocking").handler (this::testCompBlocking);
    router.get ("/testcompletablenonblocking").handler (this::testCompNonBlocking);

    server.requestHandler (router::accept) // <5>
      .listen (8080, ar -> { // <6>
        if (ar.succeeded ()) {
          System.out.println ("Server started");
          future.complete ();
        } else {
          System.out.println ("Server is not started");
          future.fail (ar.cause ());
        }
      });
  }

  private void sampeHandler ( RoutingContext context ) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep (1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    String response = "Hello...";
    context.response ().setStatusCode (200).putHeader ("content-type", "text/html").end (response);
  }

  private void testCompBlocking ( RoutingContext context ) {

    System.out.println ("Calling testCompBlocking....");
    HttpClientOptions clientOptions = new HttpClientOptions ().setDefaultHost ("localhost").setDefaultPort (8080).setSsl (false).setKeepAlive (true);
    HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient (clientOptions);

    String requestURI = "/sample";
    CompletableFuture<String> comp = new CompletableFuture<> ();
    HttpClientRequest request = client.request (HttpMethod.GET, requestURI, response -> {

      response.bodyHandler (body -> {
        String kmsResponse = new String (body.getBytes ());
        System.out.println ("kmsResponse-" + kmsResponse);
        comp.complete (kmsResponse);
      });
    }).exceptionHandler (e -> {
      e.printStackTrace ();
      comp.completeExceptionally (e);
    });
    request.end ();

    String result = "Not Success";
    try {
      result = comp.get ();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println ("Exception in getting from Completable..." + e.getMessage ());
      e.printStackTrace ();
    }
    context.response ().setStatusCode (200);
    context.response ().putHeader ("content-type", "text/html");
    context.response ().end (result);
    System.out.println ("end testCompBlocking....");
  }

  private void testCompNonBlocking ( RoutingContext context ) {

    System.out.println ("Calling testCompNonBlocking....");
    HttpClientOptions clientOptions = new HttpClientOptions ().setDefaultHost ("localhost").setDefaultPort (8080).setKeepAlive (false);
    HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient (clientOptions);

    String requestURI = "/sample";
    CompletableFuture<String> comp = new CompletableFuture<> ();
    HttpClientRequest request = client.request (HttpMethod.GET, requestURI, response -> {

      response.bodyHandler (body -> {
        String kmsResponse = new String (body.getBytes ());
        System.out.println ("kmsResponse-" + kmsResponse);
        comp.complete (kmsResponse);
      });
    }).exceptionHandler (e -> {
      e.printStackTrace ();
      comp.completeExceptionally (e);
    });
    request.end ();

    String result = "Not Blocking, please see result at Console";
    try {
      comp.thenAccept (apiResult -> System.out.println ("apiResult from CompletableFuture - " + apiResult));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println ("Exception in getting from Completable..." + e.getMessage ());
      e.printStackTrace ();
    }
    context.response ().setStatusCode (200);
    context.response ().putHeader ("content-type", "text/html");
    context.response ().end (result);
    System.out.println ("end testCompNonBlocking....");
  }

}
```

Call `localhost:8080/testcompletableblocking`, response is not sent and current thread is blocked forever.

Comment: I tried to run your code, but it appears to work as intended (except some missing parenthesis and that it is not allowed to instantiate `HttpClient`). Could you provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thanks, My vert.x version 3.5.1 and java8, I do not have sample application but I am getting this problem. I will try if can make some sample app. did you try on vert.x 3.5.1?

Comment: It was 3.5.3, but 3.5.1 works as well. To be frank, you should run the code before posting it here… If it does not exhibit your issue, it isn't very useful…

Comment: I posted my sample code, it is runnable code so you should see the problem. Call API - localhost:8080/testcompletableblocking. If you want then I can explain but it is well explain by reading code.

Comment: That's better, maybe you could remove the original code as I don't think it is still useful. I hope my answer helps. Note that I don't see in which context you would have to call `get()` on a `CompletableFuture` when working with Vert.x. I am no expert with Vert.x though – it's the first time I try to use this framework but it seems nice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that it violates [The Golden Rule - Don’t Block the Event Loop](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#golden_rule). You should not call a blocking operation like `CompletableFuture.get()` on the event loop. Similarly, `sampleHandler()` should not call `Thread.sleep()` on the event loop either, but that's a lesser problem.

The consequence is that your event loop is now blocked… so your `/sample` request cannot be processed anymore. And since the request is not processed, you `CompletableFuture` remains uncompleted… deadlock.

There are two possible solutions to this problem:

1. Use `CompletableFuture` as designed, relying on chained calls instead of `get()`, though it does not enforce Vert.x's threading model. So for example:

   ```
   comp.whenComplete((result, e) -> {
       System.out.println("Got sample response");
       if (e != null) {
           context.response().setStatusCode(500)
                   .end(e.getMessage());
       } else {
           context.response().setStatusCode(200)
                   .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
                   .end(result);
       }
       System.out.println("end testCompBlocking....");
   });
   ```
2. [Use Vert.x facilities](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#blocking_code) for running blocking code. This shouln't be necessary with `CompletableFuture` but other API's might require it. So for example:

   ```
   context.vertx().<String>executeBlocking(future -> {
               String result = "Not Success";
               try {
                   result = comp.get();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   System.out.println("Exception in getting from Completable..." + e.getMessage());
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               future.complete(result);
           },
           false,
           result -> {
               context.response().setStatusCode(200);
               context.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html");
               context.response().end(result.result());
               System.out.println("end testCompBlocking....");
           });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`get()` blocks the main thread until the future completes, however, the HttpClientRequest is executed on the main thread so the situation results in a deadlock.

Conversely, `thenAccept()` is non-blocking and merely creates a callback that is executed when the future completes.

---

Your use-case isn't clear based on the code you've provided; Is there a reason that you are using `HttpClient` and `CompletableFuture` instead of [`WebClient`](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/) and [`Future`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Future.html) respectively?

If you *need* to use CompletableFuture then you should look into [this](https://github.com/cescoffier/vertx-completable-future) project for a more Vert.x-compatible implementation.

Comment: I am not owning the code.. I am just use CompletableFuture, I can ask the owner to change it. But i am more interested why this is happening. is it something related to common thread pool..

Comment: Thanks Maxa, I thought it will have new Thread for HttpClientRequest response handler. But it wasn't. However, I think reactive nature of WebClient will work with Future.

Comment: My apologies. At the time of my initial answer the OP's question was vague and lacked a clear example; I required clarification in order to provide an answer.